# Can't set value on object's variable

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

What i am trying to do is get patient id,name,age,disease from a window from 4 text field and then search patient details using patient using id.I completed whole task but value couldn't save on object's variable though i am not getting any errors.Please guys help me where is error.Thanks in advance
Here is my code:

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

```
package hospital.management;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.Constants;

public class HospitalManagement {

    public  static void main(String[] args) {


        new Run().setVisible(true);



    } 

}

class patient{
    private

            String name,disease ;
                  int P_id,P_age;  

    public

                void get_name(String n){
                    name=n;
                }   

                void get_id(int id){
                    P_id=id;
                }
                void get_disease(String n){
                    disease=n;
                }   
                void get_age(int age1){
                    P_age=age1;
                }

            String show_name(){
                    return name;
            }
             int show_id(){
                    return P_id;
            }
             String show_disease(){
                    return disease;
            }
           int show_age(){
                    return P_age;
            }


}

class Run extends JFrame{

    JFrame frame=new JFrame();
    patient[] p1 = new patient[5];     
patient patient = new patient();               
         int cout=0;

 public Run(){


frame.setTitle("Patient Window");
frame.setSize(700,300);
frame.setLocation(100,250);

frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER,15,15));

 final JTextField jid = new JTextField(20);
  final JTextField jage = new JTextField(20);
  final JTextField jname = new JTextField(20);
   final JTextField jdisease = new JTextField(20);
 final JTextField jsid = new JTextField(20);

  final JTextArea textArea= new JTextArea();
    textArea.setEditable(false);


    JLabel lbl_name=new JLabel("Name:");
    JLabel lbl_id=new JLabel("ID: ");
    JLabel lbl_age=new JLabel("Age: ");
    JLabel lbl_disease=new JLabel("Disease: ");
    JLabel lbl_sid=new JLabel("Search ID: ");


    JButton submit = new JButton("Submit");
    JButton search = new JButton("Search");



    submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {


          @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {



           int   id,age;
     id = Integer.parseInt(jid.getText());
           patient.get_id(id);
String name= jname.getText();
            patient.get_name(name);
        age=Integer.parseInt(jage.getText());
              patient.get_age(age);
String disease=jdisease.getText();
                patient.get_disease(disease);



 } 
 });


    p1[cout]=patient;
    cout++;
    //a.c++;

    search.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {

            int  srch_id  = Integer.parseInt(jsid.getText());


    for(int i=0 ;i<2 ;i++){
      if(p1[i].show_id()==srch_id){
            textArea.append("ID: " +p1[i].show_id()+"    Name: "+p1[i].show_name()+"    Age: "+p1[i].show_age()+"    Disease: "+p1[i].show_disease()+Constants.NEWLINE);
               }

 }

 }
 });
  //textArea.append("ID: " +p1[cout].show_id()+"    Name: "+p1[cout].show_name()+"    Age: "+p1[cout].show_age()+"    Disease: "+p1[cout].show_disease());
 frame.add(lbl_id);    
frame.add(jid);
frame.add(lbl_name);
frame.add(jname);
frame.add(lbl_age);
frame.add(jage);

frame.add(lbl_disease);
frame.add(jdisease);

frame.add(submit);

frame.add(lbl_sid);
frame.add(jsid);
frame.add(search);
frame.add(textArea);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
 setLocationRelativeTo(null);


         }

}
```

Comment: Why does this have a c++ tag?

Comment: Sorry, i am new at Stackoverflow.Next time i will be more careful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Bug is here:
by this

```
patient[] p1 = new patient[5];
```

you only create an array with null values.

Here:

```
submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
 ....
p1[cout].get_id(id);
```

you try to call *get_id* from the array element, which is currently *null*.

I would recommend you to do the following:
1) in actionPerformed method

```
patient patient = new patient() // Classes should start with UpperCase letter

p1[cout] = patient;
```

2) In your example better to substitute Array with List

3) Seems that you are using getters instead of setters ;)

4) I would recommend to refactor this code snippet

Comment: Thanks man.Now i am able to save value in my object variables but it just save values in one object.i am trying to save values to every patient object when submit button is clicked like p1[0],p1[1]...it seems my program is saving values in one object and that is p1[0].How can i save values in other object like p1[1],p1[2]...
Thanks again...You save my day :)